# Order Status Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, order-status

I have a question, is it possible to get Magento to set order status to "sent" after you have shipped the product instead of "Processing"? Sometimes we have so many orders that need to be shipped and then invoiced when it is a company that is buying the product.

As far as I understand it the order status is set and stays at "Processing" until you have shipped and invoiced the order.

Hope someone can give me a tip how to solve this.

Comment: yes, you need some customization for that.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a "guide" for that?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add order status**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Setup/Patch/Data/AddShippedOrderStatus.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class AddShippedOrderStatus implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    protected const STATUS_SHIPPED  = 'shipped';

    protected ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $statuses = [
            self::STATUS_SHIPPED => __('Shipped'),
        ];
        $data     = [];
        foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
            $data[] = ['status' => $code, 'label' => $info];
        }
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertArray(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status'),
            ['status', 'label'],
            $data
        );

        $states = [
            [
                'status'           => self::STATUS_SHIPPED,
                'state'            => Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
                'is_default'       => 0,
                'visible_on_front' => 1,
            ],
        ];

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            $states
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function revert(): void
    {
        $adapter = $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection();
        $adapter->delete(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status'),
            $adapter->quoteInto('status = ?', self::STATUS_SHIPPED)
        );
        $adapter->delete(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            $adapter->quoteInto('status = ?', self::STATUS_SHIPPED)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**2. Register plugin for shipment**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Model_Order_ShipmentPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**3. Create plugin and implement your logic**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Sales/Model/Order/ShipmentPlugin.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Model\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment;

class ShipmentPlugin
{
    public function afterRegister(Shipment $subject, Shipment $result): Shipment
    {
        // implement your logic here
        $order = $subject->getOrder();
        if (!$order->canShip() && $order->canInvoice()
            && in_array($order->getState(), [$order::STATE_PROCESSING, $order::STATE_NEW], true)
        ) {
            $order->setState($order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $order->setStatus('shipped');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

P.S. Make sense to move `STATUS_SHIPPED` to some helper or model, but I've used constant in Data Patch for simplify the example