# Magento 2 How to Change or add custom order status in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status

I have created one extension for custom order status. In that, I want to add new statuses for orders. That is working fine in Magento 2.3.7.

But in Magento 2.4.4 order status is updated as per the requirement but it is not showing in the front end or in the admin.

While checking the order status label at admin or frontend it returns a blank value.

I have created a preference of **Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config** class to display the order status but it is returning blank for custom status and respective status for default statues.

Frontend Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfaX8.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVM1J.png

Backend Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n71oK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJJ9V.png

Answer (score 0):

See `sales_order_status_state` table and set `visible_on_front` to `1` for your custom status.

You can see correct example how to add status in [Order Status Magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358915/order-status-magento-2-4/358918#358918)